# Laravel redirect after login to url with port (Nginx)

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I have a server (Nginx). On this server I have Laravel application, adres to thi application is: `https://myapp.test.com:31443/login`. When I logged in correctly to the application Laravel redirect me on address: `https://myapp.test.com` WITHOUT PORT NUMBER.

Then I can't load e.g. Vue file beacuse addres is without port and in console I have 404 error "not found file".

How I can add port number to redirect url ?

P.S this redirect not work:

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'https://myapp.test.com:31443'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You using mac? Valet is the best option :(Local) https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/valet and for outside:  Valet and https://ngrok.com/.
if not using mac: (Local) https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/homestead  (outside) homestead + https://ngrok.com/

Valet and homestead makes url yourProject.test with no Port Number